# Is there any way to account for variable interaction in R's auto.arima?

Tags: r, time-series, interaction, arima

I'm using the `auto.arima` function in R's `forecast` package to build an ARIMA model with external regressors. I have a non-seasonal monthly stationary time-series dataset as shown below:

```
> dim(tsdata)
[1] 95  4
> head(tsdata)
                    y         x1         x2          x3
2007-02-01  0.0532113 -0.7547812 -1.1156320  1.15193457
2007-03-01 -0.4461565  0.5104070  1.2489777 -1.19172591
2007-04-01 -1.4087036  2.0866994  0.2835917  0.15941672
2007-05-01 -0.4960451 -1.9455242 -2.6847517 -0.06603252
2007-06-01  0.8025322 -2.9295067 -0.6049654  0.34332637
2007-07-01 -0.8053754 -0.2385492 -1.7850528 -1.29843072
```

I can use `auto.arima(tsdata[,1], xreg=tsdata[,2:4])` to fit a model with `x1`, `x2`, and `x3` as regressors. My question is, is there a way to model the interaction between external regressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way is to add products of columns to your xreg matrix like this:

```
X <- cbind(tsdata[,2:4],tsdata[,2]*tsdata[,3])
auto.arima(tsdata[,1], xreg=X)
```

That adds the interaction between tsdata[,2] and tsdata[,3].